# Uploading and processing a file with PHP and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload, upload

I would like to build a site that allows me to upload a file, and then show the progress of processing the file live. The client would upload a delimited file. Once uploaded I would verify the headers / columns in the data. If this follows a given template then I would process the lines one at a time and would like to give live feed back to the user as this happens. I know PHP is ran at the time of the get request and thus I figure the approach would require ajax to accomplish my goals. How do I go about doing something like this. Any pseudo code, examples, or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar in the past. What you need to do it start the file processing. After a set interval of time, such as a second, you can use an ajax call to poll the server to see the progress of processing the file.

By the way, I would recommend [jqueryUI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) for the progress bar and [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) for the uploader.

**Javascript**:

```
setTimeout("UpdateProgressBar();", 1000);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: // params go here
    url: // path to web method
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
         // Do stuff when file is finished processing
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (errorThrown != null)
            alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});

function UpdateProgressBar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: // my params go here
        url: // path to web method
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var totalRecords = result.d.TotalRecords;
            var recordsProcessed = result.d.RecordsProcessed;
            var percentProcessed = pagesProcessed / totalRecords;

            $('#div_ProgressBar').progressbar("value", percentProcessed);

            if (recordsProcessed < totalRecords)
                setTimeout("UpdateProgressBar();", 800);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (errorThrown != null)
                alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand about your script.
"data" and "url" in both 2 functions is same or different.

Comment: @Hueston They urls and data are both assumed to be different because you are supposed to be calling 2 different web methods. One to start the process and the other to ping the initial for updates.

Comment: It's good if you have a example detail. Maybe it spent your time.

success: function (result) {
         // Do stuff when file is finished processing
    },
you call uploadify here ?

Comment: @Huestib Uploadify has a built in progress bar, and there are many other good file uploaders that already have a progress bar built in as well. It sounds like you need to use what it already provides. In this question, the op was referring to the processing of the file after upload; therefore, my answer was geared to solving that problem.